# Delete strings before a certain string in bash

Tags: bash

I have several lines with this kind of text in a text file:

```
plink2.V1204_V
plink2.V1405_F
plink2.V12_V
xyz.V18_Z
plink2.V3049_G
plink2.V674_T
plink1.V901_V
hatzj.V7_X
```

Now I would like to delete everything before the `.V` (this is always a V). But sometimes there is also a `_V`. This I would like to leave it as it is.

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/^.*V/V/' file.txt
```

But then it deletes everything before the `_V`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the literal dot `\.`:

```
sed 's/^.*\.V/.V/'
```